# Is it ok if I don't delete files downloaded to /tmp directory of Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, imagemagick

For my Lambda function that processes images using ImageMagick (Lambda Layer), I download the input image from S3 to the /tmp directory of my function, process it and upload the output image back to S3 bucket.

In the end, I make sure that I delete the input image downloaded in the /tmp directory. But what I am observing is, it takes time to do that and that time is in seconds.

So, I just wanted to know if I can skip the deleting part of the image. Will /tmp directory be automatically cleaned eventually for me? Do I have to worry about running out of space in the /tmp directory?

Comment: I've never seen a situation where it takes seconds to delete a (non-open) file. Are you sure that's really happening? If you leave the file there *and* your Lambda function is re-invoked with a warm startup then the files left over by the previous invocation will still be there, and may cause problems for the subsequent invocation (depending on how it uses diskspace).

Comment: How are you measuring that the deletion takes seconds? When testing this, rather than measuring the _total time_ of the function, please insert debug statements _before and after_ the delete command to determine how long it takes to run. I suspect that your timing difference is actually caused by cold-starts rather than file deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) for every Lambda function. The `/tmp` directory of your execution context is limited to 512 MB.

It is totally fine to not cleanup your files, but if the execution context is reused - that happens if your lambda is invoked within the next 10 minutes - the files are still there. So yes, you can run out of space.